# How to add a SearchView into a navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-layout

I develop a navigation drawer with expandable list view, like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".HomeActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer-->
    <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"
        android:listSelector = "@drawable/selector_list_item">
    </ExpandableListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I want to add a `SearchView` into the navigation drawer, so I add it into the `ExpandableListView`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".HomeActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer-->
    <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"
        android:listSelector = "@drawable/selector_list_item">
        <SearchView android:id="@+id/sv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </ExpandableListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I got a error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think using `ActionBar` or `ToolBar` in your `Activity` to add a `SearchView` would be a good solution. You can try like this:

First, add `SearchView` into your `Menu`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Second, add actions on your `SearchView`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    // Configure the search info and add any event listeners
    ...
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And, if you want to know more details, check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

Answer (score 1):

`ExpandableListView` cannot have any children added – these are managed by the adapter. You can add the `SearchView` as a header to the adapter if you want it to be part of the list. But implementing the drawer as a fragment that will hold both `SearchView` and an `ExpandableListView` would be a better solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197791/how-to-access-searchview-in-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 1):

You can set a fragment for your navigation drawer, and set the custom view to the fragment,

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- The main content view -->
     <fragment 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       android:id="@+id/map"        
       tools:context=".HomeActivity"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

<!-- The navigation drawer-->

    <fragment
       android:id="@+id/menufragment"
       android:name="com.example.fragments.MenuDrawer"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This will help you simplify your code structure, and here is a good tutorial for Expandable list with search view that you add it to your drawer frgment http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-expandablelistview-search.html